# Adding the ability to like the Post just one time

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a like/dislike sytem on my web application. But there's a problem:  I need that the user can like the post just one time(no more), but don't know how  can i implement this. I thought, that i can make a new model, which will be connetcted via :trough.
I think i can make it so

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
end
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :posts
end
```

Comment: how are you currently implementing it?

Comment: you added the post and user class. what about the like/dislike implementation?

Comment: It's already done, i'm talking just about the ability to make a singe like from a single user

Comment: yes! show how you are implementing the like/dislike. limiting your like to only one per user will follow your initial implementation.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that this would be a very simple issue to fix. You need to stick code such as this into the model file that handles the like and dislike functionality:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :post_id, scope: :user_id
```

This is going to make sure that your post_id and user_id pairs are unique at the model level. To also bring that uniqueness validation to the database, implement something like this in the migration file for the table that controls the likes/unlikes:

```
add_index :nameofclass, [:user_id, :post_id], unique: true
```

Let me know if you have any questions on getting this to work for you